# Droppable hoverClass option is not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-droppable

I can't seem to get it to work. It works fine in Firefox, but in IE nothing happens when the `droppable` has an item held over it.

I tried using the [`hoverClass` option](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-hoverClass), and also tried just manually changing the class in "over" and "out" events. Both methods work in Firefox, but not IE. Is there a work-around for IE?

Below is my code:

```
over: function(ev, ui) {
  $(this).addClass( 'droppable-hover' );
},

out: function(ev, ui) {
  $(this).removeClass( 'droppable-hover' );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The droppable-hover class uses the outline style property, which is not supported in IE (except IE5 on the Macintosh).  At least so says [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/dom_obj_style.asp).  You could approximate it on IE using:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<style>
.   droppable-hover
   {
       border: double 1px black;
   }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```